# Programming Pattern - Single Data Structure - Multiple Methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a single data structure that holds a relatively small amount of objects (ca. 1500) and several methods that are acting on it. Is there a programming pattern to iterate the methods over the data instead of writing significantly more boilerplate code?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com to me.

Comment: I don't completely understand what your looking for, you made a comment "All methods are doing seperate calculations on the data and then return their results in a result object", why niot create your own object, which has a backing list, and the funtionas for part of this class

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear" as long as the OP does not add an example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language you are using. However, the *concept* that you are looking for is [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)).

It usually works like this:

```
map f xs
```

In an imperative style, this would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++) {

    f(xs[i])
}
```

---

I just saw the C# tag.

In C# you can use a functional style, an imperative style or a bit of both. If you use a functional style, you can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). However, your methods *should not* modify the underlying objects, since LINQ statements should have no side-effects. For an imperative style, you can just use `foreach`.

---

You can use LINQ to query a collection. For example, this will find all `x` in `myObjects` such that `f(x)`:

```
var fs = myObjects.Where(x => f(x))
```

Comment: It's not about applying the same function to each element of a list, but about applying several functions to a single list. E.g. i have a list with 1000 items and 5 functions f,g,h,i and j where each function checks for something different and needs to return it's results seperately.

Comment: Are `f`, `g`, `h`, etc. functions that you want to select on? i.e. "I want to find all elements `x` such that `f(x`)?"

Comment: Sort of. All methods are doing seperate calculations on the data and then return their results in a result object.

Comment: In that case LINQ `Select` or `SelectMany` are what you want. These are implementations of the `map` concept. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Visitor design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If the commonality between these methods is just that they take a list as an input and output a result, but the result is of a different type each time, there's not much you can de-duplicate. If there's some common abstraction to the result types instead, you could model it simply as a series of :

```
Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, TResult>
```

Then you could `Select()` the result of `Invoke()`ing these functions (or `SelectMany()` if you want the output to be flattened out).

Alternatively, you could have a series of

```
Func<TInput, TResult>
```

and iterate on the data list, applying all the functions to each element one by one. But then the results would be sorted by each of the 1500 data elements instead of a concatenation of full executions of every function.